# Can the 700D perform microfocus adjustment?

Tags: lens, canon, tamron, focus-adjust, canon-700d

Can the 700D do microfocus adjustment as is needed for the Tamron SP AF70-200mm F/2.8 Di LD (IF) Macro? or is it only available on higher end models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, Canon *Auto Focus Micro Adjustment (AFMA)* is based in the camera, not the lens. When a particular camera/lens combination is calibrated using *AFMA*, it is the camera that is adjusted. You have the option of telling the camera to use an adjustment for all lenses, or to use an adjustment only for the particular lens attached at the time you adjust it. But in either case, it is the camera that is set to act differently, not the lens.

Any AFMA adjustments made with the lens connected to one body will not carry over if that same lens is used on a different body. Depending on the exact camera model, the camera body may or may not be able to differentiate between two different copies of the same model lens. The older and lower tiered bodies that can do AFMA can not. The upper tier and other newer models can store different settings for multiple copies of the same lens model based on the lens' internal serial number.

In the case of the Canon EOS 700D/Digital Rebel T5i there is no user accessible AFMA capability. The camera can be adjusted at a Canon factory service center. In general only models with one (and sometimes two) digits have user accessible AFMA. The 50D and 70D have it but the 60D and the 40D and older models do not. (*Exceptions:* The 1D Mark II and 1Ds Mark II did not have it, but all 1-series bodies released since those two include it. The original 5D did not include the feature, but subsequent 5-series bodies have it.) None of the xx0D/Rebel and xx00D/Rebel series bodies include the feature.

Whether a particular lens needs it or not depends on exactly where within the manufacturing tolerances both the camera and the lens fall. Let's say the tolerance from the factory is anywhere between +5 and -5. Although the camera's design specification is "0", a little bit in either direction is deemed by the maker to be acceptable and within tolerances. If the camera is a little off in a -4 direction and the lens is a little off in a +4 direction, than they cancel each other out perfectly and would perform well together. On the other hand, if both the camera and lens are off in the same direction and the error is compounded, then an adjustment is needed. If the camera doesn't offer user accessible AFMA, then a trip to a factory service center for both the camera and lens would be needed. To adjust the camera requires the lens to be attached as well. If your camera performs fine with your other lenses you should request that only the lens be adjusted to match your camera.

Comment: Thanks a lot really I thought it was something that was 100% necessary like for example a mouse for a PC or something but it's only for adjustment if its not as sharp as it could be and if it's not I can just use manual focus anyways thanks also should the lens work with that body anyway still kina new to all this stuff thanks

Comment: It should. Be aware that the Tamron lens that you reference in your question is an older model that has a reputation as being good optically but slow to focus, The newer Tamron 70-200 f/2.8 is better optically, focuses faster, and includes VC (image stabilization).

Comment: OK thanks you have really helped me also the tamron lens in the question is £399.99 and I think the new one is £700 so it was out of my budget

Comment: If you have a third-party lens, will a service center do anything? When I had a camera which did not have an AFMA feature of its own, I had only lenses from that same company, and I sent them all in together. What to do in this case? (Hmmmm; perhaps this is its own question.)

Comment: I've heard of cases where the owner sent both the camera and lens to the third party lens manufacturer and they managed to match the lens to the camera. I've also heard of cases where the owner was fairly certain the camera was consistently missing in the same direction with all lenses and sent the camera and a first party lens to the camera maker's service center and had the camera "centered" there after which the third party lenses also performed better on that body. If it is that important to anyone, they are probably better off spending a little more to get a body with AFMA or equivalent

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot. Only the higher-end models can.  This generally means an XD model introduced after 2006, the 50D and the 70D (and one assumes, XXD models after the 70D). The dRebels (XXXD and XXXXD models) have never had this feature in them.

Comment: Note that from a competitive point of view, Nikon has this feature in the D7200 (and in previous D7xxx models), priced similarly to the Canon XXD range, and withholds it from the D5xxx. Pentax, however, provides it on all of their models, even the lower-end ones. (This is an example of the effect of playing catch-up in the market — the big two need to differentiate or risk lower models eating into their own higher model sales, whereas Pentax hopes primarily to get share _from_ the others and has less to lose.)

Comment: @MichaelClark; updated!