# Tethering to improve focusing

Tags: canon, focus, tethering

I use a Canon 700D, and my focus is always just a little bit off.  What is the best tethering device I could use to preview on a bigger screen?

Comment: Could you post an example of image with a focus *a little bit off* ? You might also take a look at [Why are my photo not crisp](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-are-my-photos-not-crisp)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that tethering is going to help, unless you are specifically manually focusing and just can't quite nail it. You can also try a better orientation of your subject to be more in line with the camera's sensor plane. Also, it looks like your camera has the ability to perform focus micro-adjustment for a given lens. You can try this by printing out your own device, here: http://bobatkins.com/photography/technical/focus_testing.html . Canon themselves have an article on focusing in general as well, here: https://www.learn.usa.canon.com/app/pdfs/quickguides/CDLC_Accurate_EOS_AF_QuickGuide.pdf .

Update: Sorry, it looks like I was incorrect, the 700D does not apparently have micro-focus adjustment, based on this excellent response here, by https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/15871/michael-clark: [Can the 700D perform microfocus adjustment?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69834/can-the-700d-perform-microfocus-adjustment)